# populate listbox in asp with a comma delimited array

Tags: arrays, loops, asp-classic, listbox

```
<html>
<title>Test</title>
<body bgcolor="FFFFFF">
<%
Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.open "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=123;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=123;Data Source=1234"
Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
SQL = "select * from 1234"
rs.open SQL, conn
response.write("<table border='1'>")
While Not rs.EOF
response.write("<tr><td>" & rs("Name") & "</td><td>" & rs("PID") & "</td><td>" &     rs("Coords") & "</td><td>" & rs("Items") & "<select size='3' name='itemlist'>Array through option tags here????</select></td></tr>")
rs.MoveNext
Wend
response.write("</table>")
rs.close
conn.close
Set rs = Nothing
Set conn = Nothing
%>
</body>
</html>
```

My rs("Items") contains many comma delimited values, I'd like to add each item to the listbox.  Can someone point me in the right direction? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your response.write line in the while/wend loop to this, which will create a select box with the comma separated values from rs("Items"):

```
response.write("<tr><td>" & rs("Name") & "</td><td>" & rs("PID") & "</td><td>" & rs("Coords") & "</td><td><select size='3' name='itemlist'>")
Dim opts, i
opts = Split(rs("Items"), ",")
For i = 0 To UBound(opts)
    response.write("<option>" & opts(i) & "</option>")
Next
response.write("</select></td></tr>")
```

If you need to do anything more complex like have separate select option values/text, or need to pre-select an option, then you will need to expand upon this.

Comment: Works great, I appreciate it.